# How to set the default value to the text in databinding

Tags: android

I have two edittext let's say username and password , i have one textview below it , in the textview ,what user enters in the edittext  that i have to show on it . suppose in the username edittext if the user type shayam and password shree then in the textview i have to show Username is shayam and Password is shree.

Above scenerio is working fine for me . But what's happening when user come to this screen in the textview it's initially showing me null-null ,offcourse it's right , because in the binding model intially i have no data .

Now my requirement is that :If i have no username then, by default string((i.e mentioned in string.xml as name default_val )) i have to set the textview as Username Admin and Password Admin(i.e loading the default_val from the string.xml) ,but when user type something in the editext then i have to show the generic_text i.e is mentioned in string.xml
Note : i have to peak the value from string.xml only

what i did : when the username is empty that time i will show the default string other wise i will show the generic string as i mentioned below. but why the logic is not working

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@{loginModel.username  ? @string/generic_text(loginModel.username , loginModel.password) : @string/default_val}"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"/>


 <string name="generic_text">Username is %1$s and Password is %2$s</string>
<string name="default_val">Username Admin and Password</string>
```

But the above code through me the error :

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

android:text="@{loginModel.username!=null  ? @string/generic_text(loginModel.username , loginModel.password) : @string/default_val}"

because to use string in condition u have to explicitly mention condition like null check

Answer (score -1):

You should add it in the code side and see if it works.

Like:

```
   textValue = edtText1.text + "-" + edtText2
   Textview.text = textValue`
```